# Is it possible to access other person Gmail inbox using Gmail API?

Tags: gmail-api

I am successfully able to read my inbox content using Gmail API with desktop application.
But when I am trying to read other person gmail inbox, I am getting Delegation denied exception?

So my question here, will Gmail Api allow the applications to access other persons inbox or only the person who credentials are being used in generating Client_secret file??

Comment: Do you have any more information?  Are you able to authorize against the other person's inbox?  Is there any reason you SHOULD be able to access their inbox?

Comment: Hello @Russbear thanks for your reply.

Comment: I am working on a requirement where the user registers with website with their email account and the back end job runs every day to read the user inbox every day specific to some senders.

Comment: I think I am able to get the other person authorize because when I changed the user parameter in google.authorize parameter gmail opened a page to other user requesting to allow or deny the request to read their email from a program.

Comment: Please share some light here, is there some thing I am missing which is required to read other persons inbox?

Comment: In my application I needed to attach certain threads to objects in my system, and then a user would be able to see the mails attached to that object on a specific page. For a manager role this would mean he would need to see all the emails of other users linked to that object.

How to do it? It's not so convenient, there's a setting in gsuite called "delegation", u gotta turn this on first, and then also u gotta go to your own gmail settings and in Account add all the users. I didn't like this solution so i just ended up storing them offline

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to access others Gmail inbox. To access Gmail mailboxes, use Gmail API. Gmail API gives you flexible, RESTful acess to the user's inbox with a natural interface to `Threads`, `Messages` and `History`. 
All you need to use the Gmail API is the [`client library`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/downloads) for your choice of language and an app that can `authenticate` as a Gmail user. All requests to the Gmail API must be authorized by an authenticated user. You should use server-side flow when your application needs to access Google APIs on behalf of the user.

Here's a documentation how to implement Server-Side Authorization: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/web-server

Comment: Thanks @d.datul for your information.I am able to solve the issue.I am working on implementing the approach to Web app.

Comment: this doesn't allow u to access other mail boxes as it requires authentication to the other inboxes, so it's just the basic user inbox. He is wondering if there's a way as a manager to read inboxes of it's staff without authentication

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to regulatory restrictions, I'm not sure why but it turns out that Google has not yet built any back-end support options for tracing Gmail messages within the Google Workspace administrator console

If your organization needs access to another user's Gmail account or tracks Gmail messages, I Highly Recommend using the Gmail Reader, it's a verified Google Workspace plugin, with a very user-friendly interface and a quick safe installation process directly from your Google Workspace Marketplace administrator console.

see the EZ Gmail Reader at [Google Workspace Marketplace](https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/ez_gmail_reader/1060242446754)